# Update Calculated [Field] Base on the status of a Separate Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to change the value of a Calculated FIELD depending on the results from a separate table.

I made up a small Fake DB(attached) to highlight my problem..
When the Database is open I want to be able to show on the first screen if ALL training is up to date for each employee, by changing the value of the "Calculated Field".

1. I have 5 Employees.
2. Each Employees must do 5(or more) training's.
3. All Training's must NOT be expired.
4. If a single training is expired Change Calculated Field Value to "NO GOOD"
5. If ALL training is NOT expired Change Calculated Field Value to "ALL GOOD"

I have no Idea on how to approach this scenario. Do I need to create a separate "Temp Table" to store this value?

Database found HERE: http://1drv.ms/1tX7L9M

I can't link pictures or more than 2 links yet so please look at these:
http://1drv.ms/1tXhr45

Here is my query.

```
SELECT Training.ID, Training.EmployeeID, Employees.Name, Training.TrainingID, Training.TrainingDate, TrainingList.Frequency, DateAdd("m",[frequency],[TrainingDate]) AS DueDate
FROM Employees INNER JOIN (Training INNER JOIN TrainingList ON Training.TrainingID = TrainingList.TrainingID) ON Employees.EmployeeID = Training.EmployeeID;
```

I need to check that all training for each Employee is current. If it is then I need to show this by changing the value from my first form.. The record source of the first form is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Employees.ID, Employees.Name, Employees.EmployeeID, "Help With This Field" AS TrainingStatus
FROM Employees;
```

The Purpose of this is to make my life easier and be able to see at a glance which employees need to do recurrent training and which are up to date.. I still can't visualized how this can be done.. I am a (Google is my teacher kind of access user :(  )

Comment: How do you determine when a training has expired?

Comment: By another Calculated field on the training query. That adds the months the training needs to be retaken [Frequency] to the date the training was done. The Expiration date Value is never stored in any table.. Should I save the value into a table?

Comment: @HansUp Thank you for your help.. I already have a query that does the same you just posted. Here is my version.. :  SELECT Training.ID, Training.EmployeeID, Employees.Name, Training.TrainingID, Training.TrainingDate, TrainingList.Frequency, DateAdd("m",[frequency],[TrainingDate]) AS DueDate
FROM Employees INNER JOIN (Training INNER JOIN TrainingList ON Training.TrainingID = TrainingList.TrainingID) ON Employees.EmployeeID = Training.EmployeeID;

Comment: That won't work because it does not take into account if ALL training is up to date for each employee. Out of five training's ALL 5 must be Up o date Else "NO GOOD"

Comment: Well, that wasn't intended as the final result, just an intermediate step.  But I'm running out of time for now so decided to just submit an answer in the hope I've understood this well enough to be useful.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a query which computes the *DueDate* for all training records.  Use it as the data source for another query in which you restrict the results to only those records whose *DueDate* has not already passed.

```sql
SELECT tq.*
FROM [Training Query] AS tq
WHERE (((tq.DueDate)>=Date()));
```

If that query returns the correct records --- only those trainings which have not expired --- reuse its `WHERE` clause in a `GROUP BY` query where you count up the number of unexpired trainings per each employee.

```sql
SELECT tq.EmployeeID, Count(tq.TrainingID) AS CountOfTrainingID
FROM [Training Query] AS tq
WHERE (((tq.DueDate)>=Date()))
GROUP BY tq.EmployeeID;
```

If that query also produces sane results, you can use an `IIf` expression to return *"ALL GOOD"* when *CountOfTrainingID* >= 5 and *"NO GOOD"* when it's < 5.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.EmployeeID,
    sub.CountOfTrainingID,
    IIf(
        sub.CountOfTrainingID >= 5,
        'ALL GOOD',
        'NO GOOD'
    ) AS TrainingStatus
FROM
    (
        SELECT tq.EmployeeID, Count(tq.TrainingID) AS CountOfTrainingID
        FROM [Training Query] AS tq
        WHERE (((tq.DueDate)>=Date()))
        GROUP BY tq.EmployeeID
    ) AS sub;
```

That should get you most of the way to your goal.  You would still need to join in the *Employees* table to get their names.

There may be other issues which you still need to address:

1. If an employee has not yet completed any trainings, or all his trainings have expired, should his name appear in the query (and form based on that query)?
2. Is your criteria based on 5 or more ***different*** trainings?  For example, if an employee completed only the same training 5 times in the past month, should his *TrainingStatus* be good or no good?

Comment: Thank you HansUp.... I am going over and over your approach and I think I can definitely make it work. I did not know you can use the query like you just did on the last code section where you "group by" tq.EmployeeID and using "Count" to match it against the total count of training's (ex. 5).  Since the real total training count on the real DB varies by the Job description of each employee. All I really need to do is provided this number to your code and I can say this problem is over... You have provided excellent information I thank you very much..